# In Eclipse how can we can connect H2 database using Hibernate for Maven project

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, h2

How to connect H2 database using Hibernate for Maven project?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Spring-boot initializer. Just visit this page - https://start.spring.io/

For simple Spring WebMVC select the next tools: Web, H2, JPA and i would recommend DevTools.

In application you need to create JPA repository interface like this:

package ru.arvsoft.server.core.repository;

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import ru.arvsoft.server.core.domain.Author;


public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author, Long> {
}
```

And use it in some classes:

```
@Service
public class AuthorService {

    private final AuthorRepository repository;
    private final AuthorMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorService(AuthorRepository repository, AuthorMapper mapper) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public Author getById(Long id) {
        return repository.findOne(id);
    }

    public List<AuthorShortDTO> getAuthors() {
        return repository.findAll().stream().map(mapper::mapToShortDTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

...
```